# Getting Error when archive a ios Application :- Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, mailcore

I am using Mail Core a ios applcation. When I compile it...it is giving following Error.

> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/deepikajain/Desktop/RCS-oct30/RCS/binaries/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Distribution/lib'
>   following -L not found
>
> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/deepikajain/Desktop/RCS-oct30/RCS/../mailcore/libetpan/binaries/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Distribution/lib'
>   following -L not found
>
> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/deepikajain/Desktop/RCS-oct30/RCS/../mailcore/libetpan/binaries/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Distribution/lib'
>   following -L not found
>
> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/deepikajain/Desktop/RCS-oct30/RCS/../mailcore/libetpan/binaries/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Release/lib'
>   following -L not found
>
> ld: library not found for -letpan_ios
>
> Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Can anyone let me know...how can I resolve it ?

Thanx
Deepika